# how to align label & date time picker in a row

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried to keep the controls in same line, but it is not falling into one line.

```
<div class="form-group">

                <div class="col-sm-3" style="float:left" ;>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        Starts On :
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <label>Ends</label>  

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label class="radio-inline">&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="optradio">Never</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">After</label>
                        <input style="height:30px;width:50px" type="text" name="fname"> Occurances

                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio">On
                        </label>

                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' style="width:150px;">
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div> 
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w7DR.png)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7342e6r/)

I have to show the datetime picker right side of **ON** radio button.

Comment: Since you're not providing any CSS, how about setting `display: inline-block;` on the `<div>` containing the element? And this is the reason why one does'nt use `bootstrap` - it ends up a mess. This should be one `<fieldset>` with `<label>`s and `<inputs>`, nothing more. No need for `<div>`s at all, really.

Comment: Also, inspect your css with your browser.  You'll see that the class `col-sm-3` already assigns `float: left`, so this is redundant / repetitive (and generally bad practice to have inline-styles): `<div class="col-sm-3" style="float:left" ;>`

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie - while I am actually not a huge bootstrap fan, there's nothing wrong with using it, and it doesn't **need** to end up being a mess.

Comment: It is, actually. It provides solutions for problems that aren't there, or shouldn't be there, and for the most part, encourages usage of style-specific classes, often a bunch of them, on each element. It also often tends to add a bunch of HTML-wrappers that are completely unneeded, if you know what you're doing. It's a crutch, and a bad one at that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what u r looking for

[image]

code

```
<div class="form-group">

    <div class="col-sm-3" style="float:left" ;>
        <div class="form-group">
            Starts On :
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label>Ends</label>  

        <div class="form-group">

            <label class="radio-inline">&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="optradio">Never</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">After</label>
            <input style="height:30px;width:50px" type="text" name="fname"> Occurances

            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="optradio">On
            </label>

            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' style="width:150px;">
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div> 
        </div>                  
    </div>
</div>
```

working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26914/)

make sure u link bootstrap in ur project properly